# Plain TeX cannot find eplain

Tags: packages, plain-tex, eplain

I just started using TeX on Linux after using it on macOS successfully for many years. I managed to get it installed, and after adding the following lines to my `~/.zshrc`, I can compile documents fine.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/
export TEXINPUTS="~/.config/texmf/tex/plain"
```

However, I need to `\input eplain` to make a commutative diagram and it does not work. Specifically, I get the following message:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=tex)
(./pdftemp.tex (/home/marcel/.config/texmf/tex/plain/fontmac.tex)
(/home/marcel/.config/texmf/tex/plain/mathmac.tex)
! I can't find file `eplain'.
l.4 \input eplain
                 
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: ^C
```

I have tried all sorts of things, but I just can't get TeX to find the installed packages. I know that the package is there, because I can find `eplain` in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86-64-linux`. Sorry if this is a trivial question, but would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: you have set `TEXINPUTS="~/.config/texmf/tex/plain"`  so it only looks there not in /usr/local/  You want `TEXINPUTS="~/.config/texmf/tex/plain:"` with a trailing `:` so it also searches in the standard places

Comment: Thanks, this worked -- I can't believe the issue was a missing colon!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have set

```
TEXINPUTS="~/.config/texmf/tex/plain"
```

so it only looks there not in `/usr/local/`

You want

```
TEXINPUTS="~/.config/texmf/tex/plain:"
```

with a trailing `:` so it also searches in the standard places